# How to pass variable from one class to another in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass argument from one class to another with no success. I read some posts ([Python: How do I pass variables between class instances or get the caller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501706/python-how-do-i-pass-variables-between-class-instances-or-get-the-caller); [Python-passing variable between classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113341/python-passing-variable-between-classes)) but even after that I did not manage to make this work:

```
class App(QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self, parent = None):
         super(App,self).__init__(parent)
         self.initUI()
    def on_LP(self):
        self.var = 'Last purchase'
        self.TBView = TBWindow()
        self.TBView.showMaximized()
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        Historie = mainMenu.addMenu('History')
        Historie.addAction('Last purchase').triggered.connect(self.on_LP)
class TBWindow(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(TBWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        if var == 'Last purchase':
            sql = "select * from purchases where Purchase_time = (select max(Purchase_time) from purchases)"
            args = []
```

The variable var is created in def on_LP and should be passed to class TBWindow where it would be utilized. However, I fail to pass it in there. Any suggestions how to deal with this? Thanks

Comment: Just assign it to `TBView.var` instead of `self.var`.

Comment: Put "var" as argument on TBWindow `__init__`.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these worked for me. This def on_LP(self): self.TBView.var = 'Last purchase' self.TBView = TBWindow() self.TBView.showMaximized() return following error: NameError: name 'var' is not defined and this: class TBWindow(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent = var): returns following error:     def __init__(self, parent = var):
NameError: name 'var' is not defined

Comment: I overcame this problem by declaring global variable "var" defined within method on_LP.